# Casting styled components in React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to implement animation in React + Typescript.

```
interface IImageProps {
    frame: number
    width: number
    src: string
    onLoad: () => void
}

const Image = styled.img`
    transform: ${(props: IImageProps) => css`translate(0, -${props.frame * props.width}px)`};
`
```

This throws a warning in console:

```
styled-components.browser.esm.js:1507 Over 200 classes were generated for component styled.img. 
Consider using the attrs method, together with a style object for frequently changed styles.
```

So I'm trying to use `attrs`:

```
const Image = styled.img.attrs((props: IImageProps) => ({
    style: { transform: `translate(0, -${props.frame * props.width}px)` },
}))``
```

now TS complains that:

```
Type '{ src: string; onLoad: () => void; width: number; frame: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>, "src" | "width" | "children" | "style" | "title" | ... 255 more ... | "useMap"> & { ...; } & { ...; }, "src" | ... 259 more ... | "useMap"> & Partial<...>, "src" | ... 260 more ... | "useMap"> & { ...;...'.
  Property 'frame' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>, "src" | "width" | "children" | "style" | "title" | ... 255 more ... | "useMap"> & { ...; } & { ...; }, "src" | ... 259 more ... | "useMap"> & Partial<...>, "src" | ... 260 more ... | "useMap"> & { ...;...'.
```

I can overcome that by casting ``` const Image = ... `` as any ```

But I don't like that `any`. Maybe it's an easy answer for someone familiar with styled components code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to add the `IImageProps` to the final tagged template call, to signal that those are the custom props that your Styled Component adds in addition to the `<img>` props:

```
const Image = styled.img.attrs((props: IImageProps) => ({
  style: { transform: `translate(0, -${props.frame * props.width}px)` },
}))<IImageProps>``
```

Note that you can also move the type annotation from the `(props: IImageProps)` to the `.attrs` type parameter:

```
const Image = styled.img.attrs<IImageProps>(props => ({
  style: { transform: `translate(0, -${props.frame * props.width}px)` },
}))<IImageProps>``
```

That way, `props` will be your custom interface *plus* all the built-in props for `img`.